# Манипуляции с макросами

Tags: c++, макросы, препроцессор, macro

Есть вот такой простой блок кода, который [печатает](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NMZ51mnKgfyHgJkb) `b`, я что-то упускаю из вида, почему так происходит?

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int STACKUSE = 1;


int main() {


#if STACKUSE == 1
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
#else
        std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
#endif

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Препроцессор ничего не читает из строк которые не отмечены символом `#`. Он может их менять - раскрывать макросы, но определения читать из них не будет. То есть, `STACKUSE` в вашем коде обозначает две разные несвязанные сущности. Одна - константа (её препроцессор не видит). Вторая - макрос препроцессора, который не определён в момент использования.

Comment: если не понятно по-русски, почитайте английский ответ : [C preprocessor #if expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362658)

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код не работает по причине того, что препроцессор выполняет директивы ещё до всех переменных и исполнения кода. Ваш код компилируется только потому, что по умолчанию у препроцессора все не определённые макросы равны 0 (Не знаю как на других компиляторах, но у меня и у автора, судя по всему, это так). Препроцессор не видит никаких STACKUSE. Ему нужны макросы: `#define STACKUSE 1`

Answer (score 2):

Потому что **препроцессор** в переменных не разбирается.

Хотите получить `a`? Работайте через препроцессор...

```
#define STACKUSE  1
int main() {
#if STACKUSE == 1
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
#else
        std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
#endif
```

Если же вы хотите добиться того же с помощью компилятора, то писать надо так:

```
constexpr int STACKUSE = 1;
int main() {
    if constexpr (STACKUSE == 1)
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Harry, эти варианты, что вы пишете и мне хорошо известны, я не просил дать решение, я спросил почему представленный мной код не работает по логике.

Comment: Я ответил — потому что препроцессор ничего не знает о переменных и т.п. вещах (см. первую строчку ответа). Макрос `STACKUSE` в вашем коде *не определен*, поэтому ветвь `#if STACKUSE == 1` не работает? и работает ветвь `else`.